# iMovie movie cannot be played on Mac!

Tags: video, imovie, mplayer

I have been rendering a movie using `iMovie` (10.1.14) on a Mac 10.14.6 with output to a file with some settings (resolution 540p, Quality High, Compression: Faster), but whenever I am trying to play this movie on the command line using `mplayer` I get the output

```
           ************************************************
           **** Your system is too SLOW to play this!  ****
           ************************************************

Possible reasons, problems, workarounds:
- Most common: broken/buggy _audio_ driver
  - Try -ao sdl or use the OSS emulation of ALSA.
  - Experiment with different values for -autosync, 30 is a good start.
- Slow video output
  - Try a different -vo driver (-vo help for a list) or try -framedrop!
- Slow CPU
  - Don't try to play a big DVD/DivX on a slow CPU! Try some of the lavdopts,
    e.g. -vfm ffmpeg -lavdopts lowres=1:fast:skiploopfilter=all.
- Broken file
  - Try various combinations of -nobps -ni -forceidx -mc 0.
- Slow media (NFS/SMB mounts, DVD, VCD etc)
  - Try -cache 8192.
- Are you using -cache to play a non-interleaved AVI file?
  - Try -nocache.
Read DOCS/HTML/en/video.html for tuning/speedup tips.
If none of this helps you, read DOCS/HTML/en/bugreports.html.
```

I have tried many variations of suggested options like

```
mplayer -forceidx -mc 0 -nobps -ni -framedrop  -vo gl_nosw -lavdopts threads=4 movie.mp4
```

but nothing seems to help. **This only concerns movies rendered with `iMovie`!** Any other video file runs without the slightest problem with `mplayer`.

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem? Anything I can adjust for the rendering? Maybe there are some hidden options?

Comment: Why can't you use Quicktime? Also Handbrake will convert almost anything to almost anything else, and if you simply must use a command line tool FFMPEG is the core of Handbrake and does, pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @SteveChambers I installed handbrake, and as far as I can see this is not a video player. It seems to just 'fix' the 'corrupted' videos that `iMovie` creates? Is that correct?

Comment: Correct, it would allow you to convert it to another format that might have a better chance of playing with MPlayer. Or you could use VLC, which is an excellent open source player available on all platforms...

Comment: whats the name of your movie files.  Especially the extension.